# FTP connection timeout error while trying upload file remote server

Tags: java, ftp

Here is my problem. I am trying to upload files from my local to a remote ftp server.But i get an connection timeout exception or files could not upload. If i do it on local it works but for remote server it does not.
I am trying to upload files in passive mode.

If i try;

```
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode(); //it gives timeout error,

ftpClient.enterRemotePassiveMode(); //it gives files could not upload.
```

I organize filezilla setting in windows firewall for both sides(my local and remote server). Here is a piece of my code;

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

try {

    // connect and login to the server
    ftpClient.connect(server, port);
    ftpClient.login(user, pass);
    // use local passive mode to pass firewall
    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    System.out.println("Connected");

    String remoteDirPath = "/Upload";
    String localDirPath = "C:/Users/nexgen/workspace/codes/pak";
    FTPUtil.uploadDirectory(ftpClient, remoteDirPath, localDirPath, "");

    // log out and disconnect from the server
    ftpClient.logout();
    ftpClient.disconnect();

    System.out.println("Disconnected");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Kind Regards.

Comment: Which library are you using? `FTPClient` exist in Apache Commons FTP and `it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j` too

Comment: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

Comment: Did you check firewall settings? If something works in local but not in remote probably the firewall is blocking incoming connections.

Comment: Also, did you properly set up your router for port forwarding to your pc?

Comment: yeah i gave permission to ftp server and ftp client in my local and also in remote server. Connection is succesfull but uploading is not. I can create directory in remote ftp server but can not upload my files to there.

Comment: Check filezilla server configuration, did you set permissions to read/write/append to your user?

Comment: Yeah i gave all permissions read/write/append/delete.

Comment: I know you gave permissions to filezilla in the firewall, but does something change if you _disable_ the firewall?

Comment: sorry i meant i set the permission to my user in filezilla server.

Comment: I know, I was referring to the previous comment, does something change if you disable your firewall?

Comment: Ok so it maybe the server's settings. Did you check [settings for connection timeout](https://wiki.hostek.com/images/8/87/Timeout.png)?

Comment: it is 120 in seconds.